# How to make a Discussion Group ”Sticky” in BuddyPress

Tags: buddypress

Discussion Groups sort on activity. Is it possible to make them sticky to always appear on top of the list?

Thanks.

Comment: **"You cannot make a Group itself sticky..."** per @RachelBaker 's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize:
OP wanted to make an entire BuddyPress Group sticky, which is not possible currently in core BP.

You can add this functionality using the [Group Meta custom fields](http://codex.buddypress.org/developer-docs/how-to-edit-group-meta-tutorial/) and then hooking  into the [BP Group Loop](http://codex.buddypress.org/developer-docs/custom-buddypress-loops/the-groups-loop/).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Group Forum topic "sticky" by clicking on the topic name and then selecting "sticky topic" from the Topic Admin links.

[image: Helpful Screenshot]

Comment: Therein lies my problem @RachelBaker. I cannot locate the Sticky Topic link anywhere. I have a screen shot for you below in the next answer that I post. Have a look and let me know what I might be doing wrong. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @frank13
See my comment under your screenshot for the location of the setting.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I see when I go to My Discussion Group > Admin Options > Group Settings

[image]

Comment: Those are the settings for the entire Group.  You cannot make a Group itself sticky, but you can make a topic in a Group Forum "sticky".
From the view in the screenshot above you would need to click on "Forum" -> Title of Topic.  Helpful screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/3D1f372z2B2v

Comment: Ok, thanks @RachelBaker. I have been making _Forum_'s sticky all along with no problem. The nature of my post was to understand how to make the _Group_ sticky. So you answered my question -- **"You cannot make a Group itself sticky..."** I entered this into Trac a few days ago as an entrancement request. It appears that my need requires an enhancement to BP.

Comment: Given my limited reputation here, I cannot accept my own answer for 4 more hours (a silly limitation to an otherwise awesome great resource site). I doubt highly I will be traveling back to this thread, so anyone with a high enough reputation please feel free to accept my answer as the answer because it contains @RachelBaker 's answer -- **"You cannot make a Group itself sticky..."** -- thanks !